# About the deserializeUser function not running in the passport library

Tags: node.js, express, session, passport.js

I have an application that is currently being developed.
The front end is running at localhost:3000 and the back end is running at localhost:4000.

When I tried to log in, I successfully checked the email and password in the DB using the passport library and confirmed that the log was logged to serializeUser.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JIVk.png)

Then I need to get the list of data when you go from the /login page to the /(home) page after successful login.
So I created an API get method called /plans on the server,
But When this request was made, the deserializeUser() function was not executed.

I checked the deserialize log was not printed,
and it was confirmed that the req.isAuthenticated() value also came out as false.

I know that the deserializeUser function is executed every request by automatically
saving the information in the session in Passport and then maintaining the login information
in the same session, but I don't know what's wrong.

```js
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log(`serialize user: ${JSON.stringify(user)}`)
    done(null, user._id)
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    // I want to see these logs in my server console 
    console.log(`descrialize user:::::::`)
    console.log(id)
    User.findById(id).then((user) => done(null, user))
})

app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate(
        'local',
        (err, user, info) => {
             if (err) return next(err)
             if (user) {
             req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                 if (err) return next(err)
                 res.cookie('connect_uid', req.user._id)
          res.status(200).json({
            auth: req.isAuthenticated(),
          })
        })
      }
      return res.json(info)
    },
  )(req, res, next)
})

app.get('/plans', (req, res) => {
  console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>> /plans')
  console.log(`isAuthenticated: ${req.isAuthenticated()}`)

  if (req.user) {
    res.json({ message: 'success' })
  } else {
    res.json({ message: 'not found user' })
  }
})
```

```js
const app = express()

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: 'markers-cookie-session',
    keys: [process.env.COOKIE_KEY],
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
  }),
)

app.use(function (request, response, next) {
  if (request.session && !request.session.regenerate) {
    request.session.regenerate = (cb) => {
      cb()
    }
  }
  if (request.session && !request.session.save) {
    request.session.save = (cb) => {
      cb()
    }
  }
  next()
})

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_KEY,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      domain: 'http://localhost:3000',
      sameSite: 'none',
      secure: false,
    },
  }),
)

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: ['set-cookie'],
  }),
)

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
require('./config/passport')
```

Comment: You are not using passport middleware for your `/plans` endpoint. Take a look at the example  https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/. You are using `passport.authenticate` in the controller, but it should be a middleware added to all endpoints

Comment: @Konrad my passport.js source like this ```passport.use(
  'local',
  new LocalStrategy(
    { usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password' },
    async (email, password, done) => {
      try {
        await User.findOne({ email: email }).then((user, err) => {
          // ...
          user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
           // ...
          })
        })
      } catch (err) {
        return done(err)
      }
    },
  ),
)``` Can you tell me what else to add to this for adding to all endpoints?